# error in accessing the appropriate folders in python

Tags: python, operating-system, dataset

I am not able to access the appropriate folders on my computer here using os.path.join().[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FBwQJ.png)

Comment: Please post your code and errors as plain text, not screen shots.

Comment: The error message seems pretty clear. The directory you're trying to list doesn't exist.

Comment: It looks like you dont have a directory name 'ac' in your train folder

Answer (score -1):

Try declaring the path of the file in a variable and then pass it in, make sure to use r or double slashes so you dont get errors. Also I noticed that towards the end of your error message you have a forward slash instead of a backslash.

Example

```
PATH = r"C:\Users\Public\....."
```

or like this

```
PATH = "C:\\Users\\Public\\....."
os.path.join(PATH)
```

Let me know how it goes!